# time spent in a subroutine passing variables in various ways

Tags: .net

In the following examples (see public link) we see that without passing any variable to a subroutine (variables are all declared as public) the time spent is 0.53% (!) that that spent passing variables both byval and byref.
I think however that the first method is absolutely inelegant.
Can someone help me on this problem?

All the code needed to calculate the times with the different ways of passing the variables is available at the following link. To try the three methods it's necessary to change the position of the comments. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21404842/code.txt

Comment: I'm afraid your question is really hard to read due to formatting, and really hard to understand due to basically being pseudo-code. It would be really helpful if you could provide a short but *complete* example - it doesn't need to have huge numbers of fields, but you can add a comment where there *would* be more fields.

Comment: Thanks to Jon Skeet for his interest. I changed the post with a full program example, to better understand with direct trying.

Comment: Please include the [mcve] *in the question*. (It doesn't look complete or minimal at the moment. It's not something we could just download, copy, compile and run...) It looks like you're probably not using Option Strict or Option Explicit at the moment... I would strongly suggest you do that to start with.

Comment: That was the problem! I didn't include an 'As' clause in the procedure's parameters, and this produced a large amount of time to be spent (in some way I don't understand, I'm new with .net). Proper declaration of the variables reduced dramatically the elaboration time. This program is a translation from VB6 where it worked good, but apparently that language doesn't care of this. Thank you very much Jon Skeet!

Comment: Note that if you use Option Strict, the compiler will complain about this (IIRC). I'd strongly recommend using them (or porting it to C# :)